# How to set autocomplete feature from database using LINQ?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, autocomplete

I want to set the autocomplete feature to the textbox using LINQ. I already did in one way with sqlCommands. The code is

```
  OleDbCommand cmdinst = new OleDbCommand("select distinct cst_City from cstTable", con);
  OleDbDataReader drinst = cmdinst.ExecuteReader();
  AutoCompleteStringCollection instcol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
  while (drinst.Read())
  {
      instcol.Add(drinst.GetString(0));
  }
  txtCity.AutoCompleteCustomSource = instcol;
```

With this I can add the autocomplecustom source to the textbox. Now I want to add the **same feature with LINQ**. Please any one help me..

Comment: A better question is "How to do this without reading the entire table into the `AutoCompleteSource`?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding strings to `AutoCompleteStringCollection` one by one is not efficient. Because when each string is added inner array list ensures its capacity and resizes storage (makes it two times bigger) if there is not enough space for new string. Also fore each added string `CollectionChangedEvent` will try to fire. When you adding values via `AddRange` storage is resized only once, and `CollectionChangedEvent` is fired only once.

Also you can simply apply `Distinct` operator, instead of grouping and selecting first group.

```
var db = FooDataContext();
var cities = db.cstTable.Select(c => c.cst_City).Distinct().ToArray();

AutoCompleteStringCollection instcol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
instcol.AddRange(cities);
txtCity.AutoCompleteCustomSource = instcol;
```

Comment: and how to do this without reading the entire table into the `AutoCompleteSource`?

Comment: @drzaus you can't without reading all data into AutoCompleteStringCollection. Consider to derive from that class for some custom implementation

Comment: Make sure you strip out any null values form your query when doing this.  I wasn't doing this and it would crash when setting `AutoCompleteCustomSource` with no error messages or dubugging information.

Answer (score 1):

using [Linq To SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399398.aspx)

You query reduces to

```
 AutoCompleteStringCollection instcol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
 dbContext.CstTable.Select (x => x.cst_City)
          .GroupBy (x=>x).Select (grouping => grouping.First())
           .ToList().ForEach (x=> instcol.Add(x))
 txtCity.AutoCompleteCustomSource = instcol;
```

`dbContext` is [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) derived object. Read [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1224998&seqNum=4) to learn how to create this object.

```
// custom datacontext class
 public class CustomDataContext : DataContext
 {  
    private static readonly string connectionString =
      @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=<db name>;" +
      "Integrated Security=True"; // From the app.config

    public CustomDataContext() : base(connectionString) { }

    public Table<Cst_City> Cst_City
    {
      get { return this.GetTable<Cst_City>(); }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I liked how you directly converted the result to list. +1

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to convert the above code to its LINQ equivalent. Following are the steps

1- Create a DB context object

2- Write query

3- Fetch data and display

```
YourDBNameDataContext context = new YourDBNameDataContext();
var drinst = context.cstTable.Select(item => item.cst_City).Distinct();

foreach (string city in drinst )
{
    instcol.Add(city);
}
txtCity.AutoCompleteCustomSource = instcol;
```